# Two methods in same action in struts2?

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to create an action with two methods (JSON action). I am calling them from JSP files. If I try to call an action value as 'medias' in my code, it simply run both the methods every time.

```
@Action(value="medias", results = {@Result(name="success",type="json")})
public String getMedias(){
     System.out.println("IN METHOD CALL medias"); 
    return SUCCESS;
}

@Action(value="allMediaTypes", results = {@Result(name="success",type="json")})
public String getAllMediaTypes(){
           System.out.println("IN METHOD CALL allMediaTypes"); 
       return SUCCESS;
}
```

Both method runs simultaneously, no matter which method is getting called from jsp, it runs both the methods.

Comment: Why do you prefix your methods with `get` it is not getter method after all.

Comment: Thanks, it solves my query. I just simply thinks these are simple methods. But I think struts consider get/set methods in some other way. Any way changing removing get from my method name resolves this issue.

Comment: Then you should at least vote his comment :)

Comment: How to vote a comment? I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: you dont have enough reputation yet to vote a comment

Comment: ooops, sorry my fault :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't prefix your method names with `get` - doing this has implications.

It's a good idea to name them the same as your action names for consistency, ie:

```
public String medias() {
    ...
}

public String allMediaTypes() {
    ...
}
```